# Confusion in the domain of transformation of random variables

Tags: joint-distribution, transform

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Let us assume both ranges from $0<x<\infty$ and $0<y<\infty$. Let is also assume both are having exponential densities.

I am making two different kind of transformations.

**First Transformation**

Let $U = X$ and $V = 2X+3Y$.
It becomes:

$X = U$ and $Y = \frac{V-2U}{3}$

I could obtain the joint density easily by obtaining the jacobian of transformation and then multiplying it by the joint of X and Y after replacing above values. When I have to set up the limits, I go like this:

Since $0<x<\infty$ implies that $0<u<\infty$. Further, since $y>0$ implies that $\frac{v-2u}{3} >0$ which implies that $v>2u$. So, I can write $0<2u<v<\infty$. I got the desired answer for this.

**Second Transformation**

Let $U = X+2Y$ and $V = 2X+Y$. It becomes:

$X = \frac{-U+2V}{3}$ and $Y = \frac{2U-V}{3}$

Similarly, I could obtain the joint density easily by obtaining the jacobian of transformation and then multiplying it by the joint of X and Y after replacing above values. When I have to set up the limits, I go like this:

Since $0<x<\infty$ implies that $0<\frac{-U+2V}{3}<\infty$ which implies simply $v<\infty$. Further, since $y>0$ implies that $\frac{2U-V}{3} >0$ which implies that $2u>v$. I can write $0<v<2u<\infty$. But in this case, the book is just showing the domain as $0<u<\infty$ and  $0<v<\infty$.

Comment: Both $X$ and $Y$ are positive, which implies that $V\le 2U$ and $V\ge U/2$. The support of this joint distribution is thus the cone$$0<u/2\le v\le 2u$$

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an, So, the textbook shows that both $u$ and $v$ will range from $0$ to $\infty$, well that will obviously be the case but that is also trivial. Right? So, in this case, the textbook is wrong because they don't incorporate this dependence between u and v in their answer.